# Find text starting with ... endin with (shortcode style)

Tags: python, regex

I want to find so-called shortcodes from junk of text (html basically) and replace them with something.

```
[[img src="picture.jpg" alt="Description" caption="Caption here..."]]
```

I know I can use `.find`, but how I tell python to start at `[[img` and stop at `"]]`? the problem is there might be many inside the text, even in row...

Comment: `r'\[\[img.*?"\]\]'`

Comment: Hard mode: properly match strings like `[[img alt="Descr]]iption"]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Sam suggested

```
import re
t = 'foobar[[img src="picture.jpg" alt="Description" caption="Caption here..."]]helloworld'
p = r'(\[\[img.*?\"\]\])'
foo = re.findall(p,t)

t = t.replace(foo[0],'bar')
print t
```